# Dependent Destroy not working with soft deleted parent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the code:

```
class SomeParent < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :some_child, dependent: :destroy

    def destroy
       self.update_attributes(deleted_at: Time.now)
    end

    def deleted?
       deleted_at.present?
    end
end
```

Can somebody explain why? Also, is there generally a more preferred way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the destroy method was overridden, the [callback applied to the original definition](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/destroy) was not applied to the overridden method. A simple fix is to wrap your code with the desired callback, like so:

```
def destroy
  run_callbacks :destroy do
    self.update_attributes deleted_at: Time.now
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the code above overrode the ActiveRecord::Base.destroy() which takes care of all the dependents.